# SQL Fetch multiple result counts from same set of data using same query

Tags: mysql

I am working on product data, part of which has the below structure (let's call it **product_serials**):

[image: Table Structure]

The table is a collection of product serial numbers. The `snapped` field determines whether a specific product has been purchased or not via it's serial number. Am trying to query the table to get a count of **both** all serials and also all unpurchased serials of the same `product_id`, using a single SQL query. So far using `COUNT(ps1.id) AND COUNT(ps2.id) ... WHERE ps2.snapped = FALSE` does not seem to work, it still counts the same values for both all serials and unpurchased serials, and even exaggerates the count, so am definitely doing something wrong.

What could I be missing?

My SQL query as requested:

```
SELECT pd.id AS product_id, pd.description, 
COUNT(pds.id) AS total, COUNT(pds2.id) AS available 
FROM products pd 
LEFT JOIN product_serials pds ON pds.product_id = pd.id 
LEFT JOIN product_serials pds2 ON pds2.product_id = pd.id 
WHERE pds2.snapped = FALSE
GROUP BY pd.id 
ORDER BY pd.date_added DESC
```

Comment: Please provide a complete query you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you join tables (even multiplying them) and then apply a `WHERE` condition to both.

I suggest something like the following:

```
SELECT product_id, count(serial), count(unpurchased)
  FROM (SELECT product_id, serial,
      CASE WHEN snapped THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS unpurchased)
  GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: It will select 1 for a not purchased product and Null for a purchased one. `Count` on this column will give you the count of 1s (i.e. not purchased).

Comment: Yap, this is just like using a derived table, worked for me. Thanks